# Low Search - {exp:low_search:results} shows all entries as default

Tags: low-search

Is there a way for the {exp:low_search:results} tag to display everything as a default when there is no query segment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Having a `query=""` parameter in the Results tag will trigger no results if the parameter is empty or invalid. **Omitting** the parameter altogether will allow the Results tag to show all entries.

So, this will return no results if `{segment_2}` is empty:

```
{exp:low_search:results
    query="{segment_2}"
    ...
}
```

And this will show all results if `{segment_2}` is empty:

```
{exp:low_search:results
    {if segment_2}query="{segment_2}"{/if}
    ...
}
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it seemed that now, my form doesn't filter at all.

Comment: Then share a bit more info. What does your Results opening tag look like? What is the URI for the search results? Open a GetSat thread, if that's easier.

Comment: It turned out that the problem is not with low search. Another add-on was messing with the parse order of the tags.